# How to insert into 3 tables that were created by TPT?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

I have 3 tables like this:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}

public class FeaturedUser:User
{
    public int ScoreRate { get; set; }

}
public class NormalUser : User
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }  

}
```

Also there is a form in which I can add a new User. in that form there is 2 checkboxes like this:

- Is Featured User
- Is Normal User

If in worst case user will check all check-boxes and I will expect to have same company with 2 sets of additional attributes.
My question is how can I Insert into these 3 tables, in a way I would have 1 user with 2 relations with "featuredUser" and "NormalUser".
But if I Insert a featured user and then insert a normal user I would have 2 user rows same as each other and 2 distinct "featuredUser" and "NormlUser".

Comment: You can't. It must be either `FeaturedUser`, or `NormalUser`. In particular, UI should reflect this as radiobuttons instead of checkboxes. Why do you allow to select both types at the same time?

Comment: @Dennis So there is no difference with having 2 separate tables for each user (instead of TPT) with duplicated columns?!

Comment: If each "user" can be "normal" *and* "featured", then inheritance isn't a solution. You need three entities, e.g. `User`, `FeaturedUserOptions`, `NormalUserOptions`. There will be *two* references in `User` - `FeaturedUserOptions FeaturedUserOptions { get; set; }` and `NormalUserOptions NormalUserOptions  { get; set; }`. From the database point, it will be same three tables.